# Getting ReqeustParameter as null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

jsp code is

```
<a href="#/Quiz?id=name">Start</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<c:url value="#/Quiz"> 
        <c:param name="id" value="answer"/> 
       </c:url> ">Start</a>
```

controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Quiz", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
      public String Quiz(HttpServletRequest request,Model model,HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String id) throws Exception {
String id1 = request.getParameter("id");

         System.out.println("id : "+id+" id1 : "+id1);
........
}
```

I am getting both id and id1 as null??
Why??What's wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change to

```
<a href="/Quiz?id=name">Start</a>
```

Nothing after the hash `#` sign is getting sent to the server, hence the null values. The reason why you're entering the handler method at all is that you're most likely already on the *Quiz* page